# Add a lot of columns to the grid on a form

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I have to add all 86 fields from a view based query inside a grid on a form.  The problem is that a form is very slow and the application freezes.
Is there any way to make it faster?

Comment: Is your view slow or is the form slow? To differentiate make a form with two fields.

Comment: I think that the problem is of the form, because when i add only 10 fields to the grid its open quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also try to disable auto-sizing of columns:

```
grid.autoSizeColumns(false)
```

Comment: The problem is that this method was introduced in rollup 3, i have a rollup 1.

Comment: You could try to do a kernel upgrade only (of RU7 or newer kernel). That is, do not install the application update. This will have minimal impact but will allow you to use the `autoSizeColumns` method. Of cause all servers and clients need to be updated.

Comment: I would vote this up many times more if I could. Auto size columns slows down so many forms within ax 2009.

Answer (score 1):

*Crazy clients ask for crazy things.*

My suggestion is DON'T.

As I have the advantage of working opposite you ;) my suggestion is to avoid using a Form/Grid altogether and [export the data directly to Excel](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emeadaxsupport/archive/2009/09/07/how-does-the-export-to-excel-feature-work-under-the-hood.aspx).  [Code example](http://axandhellisfunafterall.blogspot.com/2011/08/mainonserver-madness.html#example).